# WhatsApp web link preview not showing

Tags: drupal, whatsapp

While sharing a page on WhatsApp web, the link preview (thumbnail image) was not showing recently. But previously, it was working fine for a single share. Kindly support and please let us know if any further information is required.

This is the meta tag we have used and it worked properly before, `<meta property="og:image" content="https://{{domain}}/sites/banner_img_01_0_0.png?v=1657101361">`

Please find the screenshot of sample single page sharing,[image]